# Absolute minimum of $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$ on $x^2+y^2+z^2=12$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find the absolute minimum of $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$ on $g(x,y,z)=0$ where $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-12$.

I'm using the method of Lagrange multipliers: solving the system $$\nabla f=t\nabla g\\g=0$$

From $y=2t-z$ and $z=2ty-x$ I get $z(2t+1)=x(2t+1)(2t-1)$. Either $t=-1/2$ or $z=x(2t-1)$. Assume the latter. Then again from $y=2tx-z$ I get $y=2tx-x(2t-1)=x$. From $x+y=2tz$, $2x=2tx(2t-1)$. Either $t=0$ or $4t^2-2t-2=0$. The former does not occur because $(0,0,0)$ does not lie on the sphere. Thus the latter occurs. Then either $t=1$ or $t=-1/2$. We've assumed $t\ne -1/2$ so $t=1$. Thus in this case $x=y=0$.

So either $t=-1/2$ or $t=1$. In the former case $x+y+x=0$ and I got using substitutions that the minimum is $-6$. But what to do with $t=1$? Then $f(x,y,z)=3x^2$ and $3x^2=12$ (so $x=\pm 2$)...

Comment: $t=1$ case finds the maximum of $f(x,y,z)$. Indeed, it can be shown by C-S inequality that $f(x,y,z) \le 12$.

Comment: Lagrange multiplier finds extrema, not necessarily minima. $t=1$ gives the *maximum* value the function takes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt. hint: $\;2f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge -12\,$.

Comment: That's a great approach, but I was wondering why the Lagrange method doesn't work since with $t=1$ $f $ becomes $3x^2$, which is never negative.

Comment: @user5579085 The method does work, $\,t=1\,$ gives $\,x=y=z=\pm2\,$ where $\,f\,$ attains its *maximum*..

Answer (score 0):

Calling $M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

we have

$$
\min_p p^{\dagger}M p\;\;\;\mbox{s. t.}\;\;\; p^{\dagger}p = 12
$$

This can be solved with Lagrange multipliers so

$$
L(p,\lambda) = p^{\dagger}M p+\lambda(p^{\dagger}p - 12)
$$

with the stationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 \lambda  x+y+z&=&0 \\
 x+2 \lambda  y+z&=&0 \\
 x+y+2 \lambda  z&=&0 \\
 x^2+y^2+z^2-12  &=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving for $p,\lambda$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x & y & z & \lambda & p^{\dagger}Mp\\
 -2 & -2 & -2 & -1 & 12 \\
 -2 & 1-\sqrt{3} & 1+\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} & -6 \\
 -2 & 1+\sqrt{3} & 1-\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} & -6 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 12 \\
 2 & -1-\sqrt{3} & -1+\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} & -6 \\
 2 & -1+\sqrt{3} & -1-\sqrt{3} & \frac{1}{2} & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and the minimum for $p^{\dagger}Mp$ is $-6$.

NOTE:

Those points should be qualified with the hessian of $(p^{\dagger}M p)\circ (p^{\dagger}p-12)$

Here from $p^{\dagger}p-12=0\Rightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{12-y^2-z^2}$ and substituting into $p^{\dagger}M p$ after taking the positive option, we obtain

$$
(p^{\dagger}M p)\circ (p^{\dagger}p-12) = \phi(y,z) = z \sqrt{12-y^2-z^2}+y \left(\sqrt{12-y^2-z^2}+z\right)
$$

and

$$
H_{\phi} = \{\partial_{\{y,z\}}\partial_{\{y,z\}}\phi(y,z)\}
$$

with this hessian we can finally qualify the found stationary points.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question, which isn’t about the mechanics of the Lagrange multiplier method.

Comment: @amd The problems that were in obtaining the correct answer, are associated to the misunderstanding of the mechanics of the Lagrange multipliers. So I understood.

Comment: @amd The Lagrange multipliers technique always determine saddle points. Their qualification should be done with the bordered hessian of $f(p)=p^{\dagger}M p$ and $g(p) = x^{\dagger}x - 12$

Comment: The O.P. has already successfully found the minimum of $-6$, then asks, “But what to do with $t=1$?” *That* is the question begin asked, which you don’t address at all.

Comment: @amd The answer to this I put previously. It is a mistake of beginners.

Comment: @amd Please. Instead of $g(p) = x^{\dagger}x - 12$ is to consider $g(p) = p^{\dagger}p - 12$